# C++ Операторы, перегрузка операций

Tags: c++, память, перегрузка-операторов

Мне сказали , что не корректная работа с памятью в данном операторе, кто подскажет в чём та  самая "не корректная работа"?

```
Matrix& operator /(Matrix& obj) {
    int k = 0;
    float** arr1;
    float** arr2 = obj.getArr();
    float s1, s2;

    if (N > obj.getN()) {
        N = obj.getN();
    }

    if (M > obj.getM()) {
        M = obj.getM();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        s1 = sr(arr[i], M);
        s2 = sr(arr2[i], M);

        if (s1 > s2) {
            k++;
        }
    }

    if (k > 0) {
        int z = 0;
        arr1 = new float* [k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            arr1[i] = new float[M];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            s1 = sr(arr[i], M);
            s2 = sr(arr2[i], M);

            if (s1 > s2) {
                arr1[z] = arr[i];
                z++;
            }
        }
        //print(arr2, k, M);
    }
    else {
        arr1 = arr2;
        k = obj.getN();
        M = obj.getM();
    }

    Matrix* x = new Matrix(arr1, k, M);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        delete[]arr1[i];
    }
    delete[]arr1;

    return *x;
}
```

Comment: Вот полный код #include "stdafx.h" #include "stdio.h" #include "iostream" #include "time.h" #include "conio.h" #include "locale.h" using namespace std; void fill(float** arr, int N, int M) { for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) { arr[i][j] = (float)rand() / 100; } } } void print(float** arr, int N, int M) { for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { cout << endl; for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) { printf("%6g ", arr[i][j]); } }cout << endl; } float sr(float* str, int M) { float sr = 0; for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { sr += str[i]; } sr /= M; return sr; } int GetMax(float** matrix, int n, int

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, вы создаете динамически объект

```
Matrix* x = new Matrix(arr1, k, M);
```

после чего возвращаете его как

```
return *x;
```

Т.е. создается и возвращается копия объекта. Указатель на исходный объект теряется, и вы получаете утечку памяти.

Возможно, есть и другие неприятности, но маловато кода (например,

```
float** arr2 = obj.getArr();
```

кто здесь владеет выделенной памятью? кто должен ее освобождать? Без полного кода непонятно), а этот возврат - первое, что просто бросается в глаза...

Кстати, судя по

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

в ветви `else` с последующим освобождением `arr1` - если проходит первая ветвь, `arr2` так и остается не освобожденным - *очень похоже*, что и тут утечка памяти...

Comment: "Как минимум, вы создаете динамически объект

Matrix* x = new Matrix(arr1, k, M);
после чего возвращаете его как

return *x;"
Как правильно будет тогда вернуть новую матрицу , не подскажите ?

Comment: Вы еще спросите, как 2 умножить на 2 :( `Matrix x (arr1, k, M); ...... return x;`

Comment: Я почему это и спрашиваю, потому что писал так как вы, и не работает

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Без кода ваше "не работает" можно читать и как "я не смог правильно написать" :)

Comment: Вот прикрепил как ответ - полный код , вроде бы ввёл всё верно

Comment: Блин. я даже не глянул... смотрите, вы должны возвращать **НЕ** ссылку! `Matrix operator /(Matrix& obj)` - вот так! Вы же возвращаете *новый* объект, а не, скажем, свой же `*this`. Уберите ссылку.

Comment: Окей, это я понял, теперь стало указывать на оператор " operator | ", а конкретно на цикл for (int i = 0; i < this->M; i++)
  {
  arr[0][i] = sr(arrr[i], obj.getM());
  }

Comment: Ну что я могу ответить без конкретного кода и указания, что именно за ошибка? И вообще, у вас получается "дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде..." :)